# Show certain amount of prime numbers

Tags: java, arrays, primes

I have been working on some java code to show prime numbers . I have got as far as having it show all prime numbers between 0 and 100 .

How would I make it so that I could set a variable to say 20 and it would show me the first 20 prime numbers.

My Code :

```
public class PrimeNumber {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
 private static boolean prime = true;
 private static int count =  20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < 100; j++) {
                if(i == j)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    prime = true;
                }
            }
            if (prime) {
                System.out.println(i + " is a Prime:");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest possible implementation, for the OPs code.

Decrease the `count` variable and check it in the outer `for loop` till it reaches `zero`. Also Inner for-loop should check only till the current value of `(i/2 + 1)`. The other half you can always skip, the value will will divide the number will be `i` itself.

```
public class PrimeNumber {    
  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  private static boolean prime = true;
  private static int count =  20;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 2; count>0; i++) {
      for (int j = 2; j < i/2 + 1; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
          prime = false;
          break;
        } else {
          prime = true;
        }
      }
      if (prime) {
        System.out.println(i + " is a Prime:");
        count--;
      }    
    }    
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check below code for your answer:**

```
public class PrimeNumber {
private static boolean prime = true;
private static int count =  20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 2; i < count+1; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < 100; j++) {
                if(i == j)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    prime = true;
                }
            }
            if (prime) {
                System.out.println(i + " is a Prime:");
            }}}}
```